# pthread_exit(NULL); not working

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-exit

This is my code for creating some threads. I want create 500 threads in the same time, not more. Easy, but my code failed after 32xxx threads created.

Then I don't understand why I get the error code  11 after 32751 threads, because, each thread ended.

I can understand, if the threads don't exit, then 32751 threads on the same computer ... but here, each thread exited.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *test_tcp(void *);

int main ()
    {
    pthread_t threads[500];
    int pointeur_thread;
    unsigned long compteur_de_thread=0;
    long ttt=0;
    int i;

    for(int i=0;i<=1000000;i++)
        {
        ttt++;
        pointeur_thread=pthread_create(&threads[compteur_de_thread],NULL,test_tcp,NULL);
        if (pointeur_thread!=0)
            {
            printf("Error : %d\n",pointeur_thread);
            exit(0);
            }
        printf("pointeur_thread : %d - Thread : %ld - Compteur_de_thread : %ld\n",pointeur_thread,compteur_de_thread,ttt);

        compteur_de_thread++;
        if (compteur_de_thread>=500)
            compteur_de_thread=0;
        }
    printf("The END\n");
    }

void *test_tcp(void *thread_arg_void)
    {
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to create one million of threads. I would refuse if I was your OS...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pthread\_create fails after creating several threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844428/pthread-create-fails-after-creating-several-threads)

Comment: This creates a helluvalot more than 500 threads at the "same time", whether you realize it or not. Further, they're all joinable, yet never joined. Either join them or create them detached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably getting the error value which corresponds to EAGAIN, which means: *Insufficient resources to create another thread.*

The problem is that you're not joining your threads after they exit. This could be done in the if statement where you check if all ids have been used: `if (compteur_de_thread>=500)`.
Just loop over the array and call `pthread_join` on the elements of said array.

Answer (score 2):

Another option besides joining the threads, would be to detach each thread. A detached thread releases all its resources the moment it ends.

To do so just call

```
pthread_detach(pthread_self());
```

inside the thread function.

If doing so, take care to ***also*** leave the program's `main()` by calling `pthread_exit()` (instead of just `return`ing or `exit()`ing), as if missing to do so, `main()` will not just exit itself but the whole process and with this taking down all of the process' threads, which might still be running.

Comment: This answer should *probably* contain a warning about `exit()` or `return`ing from `main()` not being threadsafe.

Comment: @EOF: Yes, your are right ... ;-) sry, no comment-upvotes available to the next 7hs.

Comment: This could cause the same problem if those threads don't manage to exit before new ones are created.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

I replace "pthread_exit(NULL);" by "pthread_detach(pthread_self());" and now is perfect.

I thought that exit means :"Close the Thread"
And I thought that detach means "Thread in wait"

But no :)
Thanks all.

Christophe